# WooCommerce Wordpress Yoast Hatom Rich Snippets Solutions?

Tags: wordpress, seo, woocommerce

Rich snippets are not working inside of my Woocommerce Wordpress environment. These snippets work on a parent page except for any Woocommerce individual product pages. I have found a couple of articles that address this issue however none of them suffice.

http://www.ilmigo.com/fix-hfeed-warning-field-set-hatomentry.html

This article explains adding new class tags throughout your document, however there are several tags missing on any single Woocommerce individual page including data, author,  time, and title. Should you create these tags and hide them using CSS just for the sake of Google? What is the best solution? Are there Woocommerce plugins available for Hatom? Below is a report of an individual page taken from Google Webmasters which describes in better detail the complications I am having.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeind.com%2Fbullet-resistant%2Fwindows%2Fvision-window-with-aluminum-clamp-on-frame%2F

Answer (score 0):

we solved it simply by defining a google+ author of the posts

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2539557?hl=en

So on the product template page add this anywhere in the page-

```
<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Google</a>
```

Then you need to define yourself as a contributor to the website from within your google+ account settings here -

http://plus.google.com/me/about/edit/co